# how to write condition for preventing select all using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I've created a table with checkboxes and i want to limit the selection of checkbox. I can check maximum of 3 in the list, If i check more than 3 then it should display that It should not exceed 3. I've done it for individual checkboxes condition but didn't have an idea for ***select all checkboxes*** condition.

Can anyone help me in writing a condition for select all checkboxes which should show alert message when we select the whole data unless we select 3 items.

`Select all Function`

```
SelectAll = (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            this.setState({ Studcheck: this.state.students})
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ Studcheck: [] })
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me writing a condition for select all?

Comment: if a user is not allowed to select all the checkboxes then why bother adding that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if the length exceeds 3, than you may show an alert message else you may assign the state
You can try using this

```
    SelectAll = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        if(this.state.students.length > 3){
            alert("should not exceed three")
        }
        else{
            this.setState({ Studcheck: this.state.students });
        }           
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ Studcheck: [] })
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess she wants to show an alert when a user tries to select-all- items

Comment: @Sandhya Did the logic help you or you wanted some different stuff?

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria - Hi, This Logic helps me thanks!

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria - Thank you for helping me in this query :)